# Fail2ban fails to start after update?

Tags: server, configuration, services, fail2ban

I have been using fail2ban for a while on my Ubuntu server. Recently (after upgrading to ubuntu 15.04 I assume) fail2ban has been failing to start.

Initially, this was because the `port` option had been specified twice somewhere - I fixed that.

Now I am getting the following error:

```
WARNING 'filter' not defined in 'sshd'. Using default one: ''
ERROR  Failed during configuration: Bad value substitution:
        section: [sshd]
        option : action
        key    : port
        rawval : ", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
%(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", logpath=%(logpath)s, chain="%(chain)s", sendername="%(sendername)s"]
```

Here is a link to a pastebin of my `jail.local` configuration file: http://pastebin.com/KksbwT1r

I have removed the email addresses for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that after the upgrade to 15.04 when I check the webmin for a server that I have with the same issue, what I saw what that I had a new jail called "sshd" that had nothing defined as a filter. I deleted this jail and it now works again. To be clear, the ssh jail is still there,just the empty jail called sshd is gone. Outside of webmin I'm not sure where to find that jail. You pastebin looks clear of any invalid entries.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I found my fail2ban configs at `/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf` and `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local` (`jail.local` is the file that you should edit and `jail.conf` is the default settings one I think). Would it be possible for you to post your fail2ban config? I would find it helpful to compare your working one against my failing one :)

Comment: Update: I found another file called `jail.conf.dpkg-dist` in that directory too. I assume it's the newest default config file, so I backed up and deleted the old ones and reconfigured my fail2ban install using the new config file it seems to be working now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I found sshd jail in `jail.d/defaults-debian.conf` wwith only 2 lines, so no filter no action

Comment: Thanks, I had also a sshd jail only visible in Webmin. Deleted it and it works again :)

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 16.04 had the same issue out of a sudden:

> dec 17 08:58:41 xxx fail2ban-client[1342]: ERROR  Failed during configuration: Bad value substitution: option 'action' in section 'sshd' contains an interpolation key 'port' which is not a valid option name. Raw value: '%(action_)s'

it turns out that on Ubuntu inside  jail.d/defaults-debian.conf there is a jail confing that contained nothing but:

> [sshd]
>
> enabled = true

Commenting this lines out fixed the issue above.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. 
**Fix** was: Port in jail.conf was missing.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I modified `defaults-debian.conf` in the following way and `fail2ban` service started again.
`[sshd]
enabled  = true
port     = ssh 
filter   = sshd
maxretry = 6`

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 I ran into similar issues. For me it was sufficient to replace the `.conf` files with the `.conf.dpkg-dist` files.

```
sudo mv paths-common.conf paths-common.conf.old
sudo mv paths-common.conf.dpkg-dist paths-common.conf
sudo mv paths-debian.conf paths-debian.conf.old
sudo mv paths-debian.conf.dpkg-dist paths-debian.conf
```

I also had to apply [these changes](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/commit/9876dd44f93a0b012108ea1aceeccee21be03cb9) to `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`, essentially replacing all occurrences of `imap3` with either `imap` or `imap2`.

Afterwards fail2ban started without problems.